# As a snake impaled, I am not free

Tags: riddle

As a snake impaled, I am not free.
Rather, I am displayed for all to see.
Why do people not mourn me?
Instead they want more of me.
You want more?
Four is my door.

Who am I?

note:

I added 2 lines to the riddle.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I think I got it now.

> **The dollar sign.** The $ looks like a snake impaled, displayed in front of all dollar amounts, is not mourned for contributing to one's wealth, and of course, people want more. "Four is my door" tipped me off, where it refers to the number 4 on the keyboard having the dollar sign as its shift-text.

Comment: You get my vote for figuring out that 4 and $ are the same key.

Answer (score 4):

Is it perhaps a

> Belt?
>  A belt  is sort of serpentine. It's "impaled" by prong which fastens it, so it's not free. Belts are worn visible to everyone.  No one mourns them. There's a demand for them, since people buy them.

Comment: Very good answer, but there is a better one.

Comment: People usually don't want to get "more" of a belt, due it means they have increased.

Answer (score 3):

Is it a

> **Wrist Watch (with leather strap)**

As a snake impaled

> Has pierced holes to insert buckles in leather starp.

I am not free

> Tied to the wrist

Rather, I am displayed for all to see.

> Displayed for all to check time

Why do people not mourn me?

> We won't mourn when the watch is dead

Instead they want more of me.

> Instead we repair, or buy new batteries to run it again

Comment: I added 2 lines to the riddle. Thanks for your answer, nice and creative.

Comment: Or—for the last one—metonymically, crbcyr nyjnlf jnag zber gvzr. [(decode)](http://rot13.com/index.php)

Answer (score 2):

First idea I could come up with:

> **A ring**. The idea stems from the explanations of other answers: snake impaled may refer to the finger going through the center, it is worn to be shown off and displayed. The ring is often a symbol of celebration, as opposed to mourning. And of course, rings are worth something, be it sentimental or what have you.
>
>  As for the hint, "4 is my door", he refers to the fourth finger, also known as the Ring finger, where a ring is most commonly worn.

Comment: Very clever, but even if the ring is a snake, it is not impaled. It is just wrapped around your finger. Kudos for creativity +1

Answer (score 1):

How about:

> Pharmacy logos?
> http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/d9/Bowl_hygeia.svg
> 1 - Bowl of Hygieia, the internationally recognised symbol of pharmacy (the profession).
> or this one
> http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/19/Asclepius_staff.svg
> 2 - Rod of Asclepius, the internationally recognised symbol of medicine.

As a snake impaled, I am not free.

> Although the snake entwines in the classical explanation, it's rather ambigous in the logo (2 dimensional images, especially monochrome, often suffer from difference in 3 dimensional topological interpretation).

Rather, I am displayed for all to see.

> Logo displayed on pharmacies for all to see.

Why do people not mourn me?

> Dude your a picture, calm down.... :)

Instead they want more of me.

> Helping and getting helped by others is considered to be a good thing.

You want more?

> Yes

Four is my door.

> The Chinese, Vietnamese, the Korean and the Japanese are superstitious about the number four because it is a homonym for "death" in their languages (wiki). So with death at your door or four being the next door (as in option to choose from), you go to the pharmacy (or infirmary).
> or something like
> Four is the number of classical elements (earth, water, air and fire). These elements are the root for alchemy, which is the root or predecessor of chemistry. (Maybe my last point is a little bit far fetched, but whatever.)

Comment: Unfortunately, the riddle's author discredits when the 'snake' is wrapped around, not impaled. My first idea, a ring, also was a wrap-around type of word play on the term, "impaled", but was also counted wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Are they,

> **Animals in Zoo**

As a snake impaled, I am not free.

> Animals kept in a cage.

Rather, I am displayed for all to see.

> They all kept for us to see.

Why do people not mourn me?

> People do not mourn if any of animal dies.

Instead they want more of me.

> Instead we want more spices of them to see.